# shell script to connect to a sql server database server and insert the results from a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I usually work in .NET and windows.But recently I have a problem which involves the unix server. The unix server is having text files whose data needs to be inserted to sql server database in another windows server. I need to insert the data on regular time interval of 15 mins automatically. I will be able to do the same by writing a windows services...but no idea in Unix..please help..

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very generic so i'd try to answer in a generic way.

First, create a `crontab` entry that will trigger your script every 15 minutes

```
*/15 * * * *    /path/to/your/script.sh
```

then, assuming you have to push every line of a file inside a table, you have to do something like this in your script

```
#!/bin/bash

# read every line of the output of your script
/path/to/your/output_script | while read line 
do

    # push data into db
    /path/to/your/sqlclient [auth params] -c "INSERT INTO yourtable (field) VALUES ('$line');"

done
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I need one more help on this.Instead of reading the file from  a file, I need to read it from an output of another script.How can I go ahead with this?

Comment: I am not able to connect to SQL server.I am using AIX UNIX and i dont have any drivers to do this task.I have been adviced to install unix odbc driver,TDS,cpp,cpp lib packages to support the connection.I am not sure on this..please help.Is it not possible to do with minimum instalations of only the driver.

Comment: what kind of server are you connecting to? SQL Server 2008?